# Update Jenkins with selected plugins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have got a update for Jenkins, current version (Jenkins ver. 2.89.3) to (2.107.2). That includes the update on ansible plugin, which i dont want to do it because the latest version of ansible plugin is not compatible to my environment. How to upgrade Jenkins excluding that particular ansible plugin changes

OS: Rhel7
current version:Jenkins ver. 2.89.3

Answer (score 1):

In my environment, updating Jenkins application doesn't automatically update your plugins. You'd have to update your plugins in the settings options.

Also, my Jenkins instance is configured using tomcat & nginx reverse proxy.

Comment: Can you tell me how you are upgrading jenkins if it  is a RHEL box,

Comment: I manually update Jenkins using the jenkins.war file in my tomcat dir. Of course I rename jenkins.war to ROOT.war